# How to find sub string from SQL message?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I have data like:-

> 1)Your assigned carrier is {carrier_name}. They will be reaching out to you soon to schedule pick-up, but feel free to call them at {carrier_phone} and reference {reference_id}. They are open now and will be until {close_time}.
>
> 2)The {vehicle_owner} indicated that their {body_style} was picked up. Would you provide an update on the assignment or mark it complete?

I want to find all the values between brackets -> `{___}`.

Only particular message should be found between brackets. There could be any value between them.

How can I find it out using query?

Comment: Add some sample table data and the expected result - as well formatted text. Also show us your current query attempt.

Comment: This is formatted data.Here, 1 is id and 2 is Message. @jarlh

Answer (score 2):

If the string always follows the repeating pattern of `'..{..})'` one method to solve this uses a CSV Splitter function by Jeff Moden, replacing the second delimiter with the first delimiter, and getting only the second sets using [modulo (`%`)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190279.aspx):

```
select 
    Id
 , col = x.item
from t
  cross apply (
    select Item = ltrim(rtrim(i.Item))
      from [dbo].[delimitedsplit8K](replace(t.col,'}','{'),'{') as i
      where ItemNumber%2=0
      ) x
```

test setup: http://rextester.com/VDBK82975

returns:

```
+----+---------------+
| Id |      col      |
+----+---------------+
|  1 | carrier_name  |
|  1 | carrier_phone |
|  1 | reference_id  |
|  1 | close_time    |
|  2 | vehicle_owner |
|  2 | body_style    |
+----+---------------+
```

Splitting strings reference:

- [Tally OH! An Improved SQL 8K “CSV Splitter” Function - Jeff Moden](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Tally+Table/72993/)
- [Splitting Strings : A Follow-Up - Aaron Bertrand](https://sqlperformance.com/2012/08/t-sql-queries/splitting-strings-follow-up)
- [Split strings the right way – or the next best way - Aaron Bertrand](https://sqlperformance.com/2012/07/t-sql-queries/split-strings)
- [**`string_split()`** in SQL Server 2016 : Follow-Up #1 - Aaron Bertrand](https://sqlperformance.com/2016/04/sql-server-2016/string-split-follow-up-1)

---

function used in the test:

```
create function [dbo].[delimitedsplit8K] (
      @pstring varchar(8000)
    , @pdelimiter char(1)
  )
returns table with schemabinding as
 return
  with e1(N) as (
    select 1 union all select 1 union all select 1 union all 
    select 1 union all select 1 union all select 1 union all 
    select 1 union all select 1 union all select 1 union all select 1
  )
  , e2(N) as (select 1 from e1 a, e1 b)
  , e4(N) as (select 1 from e2 a, e2 b)
  , ctetally(N) as (
    select top (isnull(datalength(@pstring),0)) 
      row_number() over (order by (select null)) from e4
  )
  , ctestart(N1) as (
    select 1 union all
    select t.N+1 from ctetally t where substring(@pstring,t.N,1) = @pdelimiter
  )
  , ctelen(N1,L1) as (
    select s.N1,
      isnull(nullif(charindex(@pdelimiter,@pstring,s.N1),0)-s.N1,8000)
    from ctestart s
  )
 select itemnumber = row_number() over(order by l.N1)
      , item       = substring(@pstring, l.N1, l.L1)
   from ctelen l
;
```

---

Recursive cte version (no additional function required)

```
;with cte as (
  select 
      id
    , val = left(stuff(col, 1, charindex('{', col),'')
              , charindex('}', col) - charindex('{', col) - 1
            ) 
    , rest = stuff(col, 1, charindex('}', col) + 1,'') 
  from t
  where col like '%{%}%'
  union all
  select 
      id
    , val = left(stuff(rest, 1, charindex('{', rest),'')
              , charindex('}', rest) - charindex('{', rest) - 1
            ) 
    , rest = stuff(rest, 1, charindex('}', rest) + 1,'') 
  from cte
  where rest like '%{%}%'
)
select id, val
from cte
order by id, val;
```

returns:

```
+----+---------------+
| Id |      col      |
+----+---------------+
|  1 | carrier_name  |
|  1 | carrier_phone |
|  1 | reference_id  |
|  1 | close_time    |
|  2 | vehicle_owner |
|  2 | body_style    |
+----+---------------+
```

Comment: Not working.
My table name is [Tbl_BotMessageLibrary] and columns are [Id] and [Message].

This query is going to fire on database.

Comment: For this answer, you need to create the function used to split the values. The function is in the first reference, in the rextester test link, and now also at the bottom of the answer.

Comment: @DeepJadia Added a recursive cte version that doesn't require a function.

Answer (score -1):

> This can be achieved through **SUBSTRING** and **CHARINDEX**

```
SUBSTRING(@Text, CHARINDEX('%{%',@Text), CHARINDEX('%}%',@Text))
```

CHARINDEX gives the value of the first occurence of the search string. Providing those value in SUBSTRING, you can get the desired output.